# Set number of digits after decimal

Tags: python

I'm trying to set 3 digits after point but it returns me 0.03 instead of 0.030
Here's the code:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 3
a = float(input())
qur = []
x = 2
b = a / 100
while x < 12:
    qur.append(b)
    b = (a * x) / 100
    x += 1
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in qur]))
```

Comment: Yes I googled and much. Maybe my english is too bad but it always gives me not what I want

Comment: Do you want to set it in the variable? Or only when printing it?

Comment: Setting the `decimal` context isn't going to affect things that *aren't actually `decimal.Decimal`s*...

Comment: UnholySheep, either way would work for me

Comment: For formatting the output to display a fixed number of digits Python provides string formatting (see @Daniel's answer)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `decimal`s, so setting their precision has no effect. For output with a fixed number of digits, use string formatting:

```
print(" ".join('{0:.3f}'.format(i) for i in qur))
```